# What apt command is used to check for the soundness of the installation, or misconfiguration?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

Usually an `apt-get -f install` shows stuff that needs fixing and another other `apt-get install xxxx` displays any present misconfigurations.

Is there a particular `apt` command that displays the state of the installation and any flaws that may be present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's `check`:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

From `man apt-get`:

> check
>
> check is a diagnostic tool; it updates the package cache and checks for broken dependencies.

Comment: It turns out that `apt-get check` doesn't do what I need it for. The KDE 5 Plasma shell on the system is broken and a number of packages were not installed because of broken dependencies. How do you find incomplete configurations, ie the type you don't know about until you try to run them?

Comment: @vfclists Now i am confused. Could you please give a complete example?

Comment: You answer is technically correct so  I have to leave it as it is. I run a dist-upgrade which broke kde 5 on sid without realizing it until I rebooted and tried to login to the desktop again. So I tried `apt-get plasma-desktop` and I get a whole slew of errors listed in this pastebin, http://pastebin.com/njJVrdWR . How would I know that the apt package configuration is in such a state without trying to install something.

Comment: @vfclists you should post a new question.

Comment: @GnP Here is the new question - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315545/besides-apt-check-what-apt-command-checks-for-the-soundness-of-packages-config?noredirect=1&lq=1