# Besides 'apt check' what apt command checks for the soundness of packages configuration?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I asked this question earlier [What apt command is used to check for the soundness of the installation, or misconfiguration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315249/what-apt-command-is-used-to-check-for-the-soundness-of-the-installation-or-misc) and although the answer was correct `apt check`, it did not fix my problem when I tried it, as in the quoted text below.

So the question is how do you analyze the condition of your packages to ensure that everything is hunky-dory before an `apt install` command informs you about it?

> I run a dist-upgrade which broke kde 5 on sid without realizing it
>   until I rebooted and tried to login to the desktop again. So I tried
>   apt-get plasma-desktop and I get a whole slew of errors listed in this
>   pastebin, [pastebin.com/njJVrdWR](http://pastebin.com/njJVrdWR) . How would I know that the apt
>   package configuration is in such a state without trying to install
>   something

Here is the output of trying to reinstall the plasma-desktop.

```
vfclists@hp01:~$ sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop
[sudo] password for vfclists:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 plasma-desktop : Depends: breeze but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: kactivitymanagerd but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: kde-cli-tools but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: oxygen-sounds but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: plasma-integration but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: plasma-workspace but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: polkit-kde-agent-1 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libkworkspace5-5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**UPDATE:** I want to note that I am currently running a bleeding edge configuration with the `uname` output below. The question is more concerned with knowing how apt detects and informs about misconfigurations, not about actually fixing my problem which is better dealt with in the Siduction forum.

```
Linux hp01 4.8.0-towo.1-siduction-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT siduction 4.8-1 (2016-10-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: would you please add the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro There no is no output from `grep hold`, but after looking at the raw list I see that plasma-desktop is listed for deinstall and so is xrdp and xserver-xorg-video-modesetting. I have to emphasize that I am running Siduction which is a variant of Debian Sid which is using the 4.10 kernel dated 2016-10-04, very bleeding edge. I will update the question with these facts, but the question still concerns the way apt works, not fixing a bleeding edge configuration.